# .htaccess allow extension, allow no extension, and allow trailing slash

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I am having trouble coding my htaccess file to do what I need it to do.

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.tempsite.com/400.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.tempsite.com/500.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^pricing/?$ pricing.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^support/?$ support.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^learning/?$ learning.php  [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

So from my testing and my knowledge what this does is:

- sets up a 404 and 500 error page redirect
- any pages that end with a slash, redirect to .php
- any pages that end with a any extension, redirect to .php

This does what im wanting HOWEVER I don't want to have to add each page like: `RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [NC]` every time I create a new page so how do I write a `RewriteRule` that does the same thing (allows the page with a slash and without) but for all domain pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Instead of all lines from `RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php`...

Comment: hey man! thanks for the comment however this didnt work for me :(

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Im not quite sure how to error check htaccess files - nothing appears in console

Comment: Try now (I had forgotten a ?)